# Send a cmd msg in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

What is the correct syntax in order to send the message in `var` to the current user?

```
Shell ("cmd MSG " & Environ("username") & " /TIME:5 " & var, vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing? Are you getting errors?  Do you want to offer some details maybe?

Comment: First off, I don't think you need to start the command with `cmd`. However, if you do start it that way, I think you need the `/C` switch.

Comment: I am getting a nonspecific syntax error, whether or not I use `cmd`.

Comment: Would `var` need quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
Shell "MSG " & Environ("username") & " /TIME:5 " & var, vbNormalFocus
```